# Incorrect link in pagination, prestashop

Tags: javascript, php, pagination, prestashop

i'm use prestashop 1.6 and i have problem about link in pagiantion (eg category product site).

The problem concerns only one category of products. Link gets on the end a #/page-1 eg http://domena.com/3-category#/page-1. Properly it should be 3-category?p=3. If you turn off the js is the link is correct. Why is this happening?

Comment: That error is caused from the BlockLayered module, im on my way to solve it, when i got an answer i will post it here.

Comment: Well, i found a very simple solution, at least it worked for me. In the blocklayered module folder, you will find the file "blocklayered.js", and inside the theme js blocklayered module folder, you will find a compressed version of the file. Just replace the content of the compressed version with the js from the main modules folder.

Answer (score 2):

Try to disable block 'Layered navigation' in , it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

This problem also the reason for double-content because of duplicated titles on the pages. In order to solve that , I used this method ;
After replacing your blocklayered.js with uncompressed version, 
find 
`$title = $category_title.$title;` 
in blocklayered.php that is located in /modules/blocklayered/ folder.

Then replace it to

```
if(isset($category_metas['meta_title'])){
        $title = $category_metas['meta_title'];
}else{
        $title = $category_title.$title;
}
```

So, you don't have to disable blocklayered module . Hope this helps.